# UICollectionView not showing last cell in iOS 8 only

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView which has one section, and is laid out in one row. In iOS 9 I have no issues, but in iOS 8 the last cell doesn't show. The cell is there, but for some reason the contentSize of the collection view is set incorrectly in iOS 8. It sizes perfectly to the second last cell. Has anyone run in to this issue? How can it be solved?

I am using Autolayout to size the cells. I am using a custom UICollectionViewCell that is loaded from a nib. I am registering the cells using the following code:

```
 [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:kMyCustomCellIdentifier];
```

I am using a generic UICollectionViewFLowLayout, set to scroll horizontally. I am running Xcode 7.3.1.

Comment: Can you confirm there is no error regarding the frame of `UICollectionView`? Did you change the device type too while testing it on iOS8?

Comment: There is no error message. I have tried it on iPhone 4s, 6 and 6s on iOS8 and iOS9. In every case in iOS9 the contentSize is set correctly, and in iOS8 it is set to fit all the cells except the last one exactly.

Comment: May be you have not correctly added auto layout constraint. Can you share the screenshot and some code??